# Extract a property from type JSON property

Tags: json, powershell

I have some Azure usage data in the structure as returned from the Azure management cmdlet `Get-UsageAggregates`. This has some information in a property of type Json, from which I want to extract a sub-property.

These data are contained in variable `$usage`. If I execute

```
$usage.UsageAggregations.properties | 
    select-object metercategory,metersubcategory,unit,quantity
                 ,@{Name="resource"; Expression={$_.InstanceData }}
```

I get a list of objects like this:

```
MeterCategory    : Storage
MeterSubCategory : Geo Redundant
Unit             : GB
Quantity         : 3.76344
resource         : {"Microsoft.Resources":{"resourceUri":"/subscriptions/[GUID]/resourceGroups/default-storage-
                   northeurope/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/MyAccountName","location":"eunorth"}}
```

I would like to see the "MyAccountName" instead of the JSON string. How can I do that?

I tried to use

```
$usage.UsageAggregations.properties | 
    select-object metercategory,metersubcategory,unit,quantity
                 ,@{Name="resource"; 
                    Expression={$_.InstanceData | 
                                ConvertFrom-Json | 
                                select-object -Property Microsoft.Resources.resourceuri }}
```

But the output is

```
MeterCategory    : Storage
MeterSubCategory : Geo Redundant
Unit             : GB
Quantity         : 3.76344
resource         :  @{Microsoft.Resources.resourceuri=}
```

Adding `.value` after `resourceuri` also did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist of your question is how to extract the string `MyAccountName` from the following JSON string (pretty-printed and simplified):

```
$json = @'
{
  "Microsoft.Resources": {
    "resourceUri":  "/subscriptions/[GUID]/resourceGroups/.../MyAccountName",
    "location":  "eunorth"
  }
}
'@
```

Combine `ConvertFrom-Json` with the `-split` operator:

```
(($json | ConvertFrom-Json).'Microsoft.Resources'.resourceUri -split '/')[-1]
```

- `ConvertFrom-Json` converts the JSON string into a custom object with a top-level property `Microsoft.Resources` property, which in turn is a custom object with properties `resourceUri` and `location`.
- `.'Microsoft.Resources'.resourceUri` therefore returns the value of the `resourceUri` JSON property - note the need to *quote* `'Microsoft.Resources'` so as to ensure that its *embedded* `.` is considered *part of the property name* rather than as a separator *between* property names.
- `-split '/'` splits the value into tokens by `/` and returns them as an array.
- `[-1]` references the *last* element of that array, which is `MyAccountName` in this case.

---

As for **what you tried**:

**`Select-Object` doesn't support property *paths*, only *top-level property names***.
In other words, you can only extract top-level properties from input objects; you cannot drill down into them.

Therefore, you can extract top-level property `Microsoft.Resources` - whose name just happens to contain a `.` itself - but not also *its* `resourceUri` property.

If you attempt to do so, the **whole argument is considered a top-level property name** literally named `Microsoft.Resources.resourceUri`.
**If the input object has no such property, the property is *created* with a value of `$null`** for the output object.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

Generally, **to make `Select-Object` extract a property *value*** - as opposed to the default behavior of returning a *custom object* with that property, you must **use `-ExpandProperty`** instead of `-Property`.

Note that if you *had* used **`-ExpandProperty`**, the problem would have become more obvious, because PowerShell then **reports an error if a (top-level) property by the given name cannot be found**<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
> $json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Microsoft.Resources.resourceUri
Select-Object : Property "Microsoft.Resources.resourceUri" cannot be found.
...
```

---

<sup>[1]Curiously, though, if you attempt to *quote* a *component* of a `.`-separated string, `Select-Object` simply passes the input object through -
 see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6125).</sup>