# Selecting items from sub-objects

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the Username from Get-AppxPackage.  Unfortunately that property is nested quite deep. In my head it would be something like this (but it doesn't work):

```
Get-AppxPackage -Allusers | select $_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityID.Username | where-object {$_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityID.UserName -notlike "defaultuser*"}
```

In UserName, there could be either 1 or 2 items depending on the package.  If there are 2 items, I want to put the one that is not like 'defaultuser*' into a variable as a string.

```
Running Get-AppxPackage -Allusers | where-object {$_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityID.UserName -like "defaultuser*"}
```

Should return some example packages with multiple UserName items that are built into Windows 10.

Comment: So you just want to return just one username?

Answer (score 1):

- The following extracts the usernames that don't start with `defaultuser` from among all users that have installed AppX packages on the local machine.
- Given that there are likely to be many duplicates, the result is piped to `Sort-Object -Unique` to get the sorted, unique set of resulting usernames.

```bash
# NOTE: Only works in *Windows PowerShell*; see below for PS v7.1+ solution.

#requires -RunAsAdministrator

Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers |
  ForEach-Object {
    @($_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityID.Username) -notlike 'defaultuser*'
  } |
  Sort-Object -Unique
```

Note the use of `@(…)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), which ensures that the LHS is an *array*.

With a *collection* (such as an array) as the LHS, PowerShell comparison operators such as `-notlike` act as *filters* and return an *array of matching items* rather than a Boolean - see [about_Comparison_Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features).

Therefore, the above simply *filters out* usernames that start with `defaultuser` from the (potential) array of usernames reported by `$_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityID.Username`

A note re **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) compatibility**:

- As of this writing, the underlying `Appx` module that ships with Windows itself is *incompatible* with PowerShell (Core) since v7.1.
- With *limitations* - decreased performance, limited type fidelity - you can still use it, namely via a hidden instance of *Windows PowerShell* utilizing the [Windows Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility) feature.
- Making the module compatible again is planned, but there's no telling when that will happen - see [GitHub issue #13138](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13138#issuecomment-1820195503) for details.
- It is the type-fidelity limitations that make the above *not* work in PowerShell 7.1+, because - due to limited serialization depth - the `.PackageUserInformation` property turns into a *string* value, so that the `.UserSecurityID.Username` property access yields `$null` (because `[string]` has no such properties). You can work around this with string parsing (which is invariably less robust than object-based processing):

  ```bash
   # PS v7.1+ solution (also works in WinPS)

   #requires -RunAsAdministrator

   Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers |
     ForEach-Object {
       @([string] $_.PackageUserInformation -replace '^.+\[(.+?)\].+$', '$1') -notlike 'defaultuser*'
     } |
     Sort-Object -Unique
  ```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `... | select $_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityID.Username`

- `$_` is only ever meaningfully defined inside *script blocks* (`{ ... }`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55667981/45375).
- Even without it, you cannot provide property *paths* to [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (whose built-in alias is `select`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48663400/45375).

Comment: This is not getting the respect it deserves as an answer :) Perfect answer, beautifully explained. Also, fixed a query I had so MANY THANKS to the OP with the question and this user with the fix.  Iterating over the list is exactly what was needed. IN python, I could do this with my eyes closed, in Powershell? no idea!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @KayCee; my pleasure. I've tweaked the answer a bit to show the need to run the command with elevation and to directly add `Sort-Object -Unique`. I've also added information about PowerShell 7+ compatibility. As for answers not getting respect: in my estimation the site provides insufficient guidance to newcomers with respect to accepting answers and the importance of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Filter your object first, then select and output the result - you can select "nested" properties using a calculated property structure:

```
$PackagesAndUsers = Get-AppxPackage -Allusers | Where-Object { $_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityID.UserName -notlike "defaultuser*"} | Select Name, @{N='UserName';E={$_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityID.UserName}}
```

Now you have all the packages and users in a single object which excludes `defaultuser*`
From `$PackagesAndUsers` - you can pick anything you like out of this to populate your string.

Bear in mind there could still be more than one user in the Username field if there's more than one user on your computer